# Background image on mobile Bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I've got 3 rows:
top, middle, bottom divs. In the top and bottom divs, there's a foreground image and in the middle div there's a background image.

On mobiles, the middle div doesn't not resize like the top and bottom and is way too large. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <img src="img/top.jpg" width="640" height="582" alt="" title="" border="0" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12" style="background:url('img/middle.jpg') no-repeat; height:245px;">
            Hello world.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <img src="img/bottom.jpg" width="640" height="314" alt="" title="" border="0" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--/.container-fluid -->   
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to get the div with the background-image to adjust to the screen?

Comment: If you are looking to do it with CSS then you can try `background-size:cover;`

Comment: I tried to add background-size:cover; in the style of the middle div but doesn't work.

Comment: It depends what browsers you are wanting to make the background work on.

Comment: you could always cheat and change the background image to an img? You can absolutely position content on top. Bit hacky, but probably the best approach in terms of browser compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `background-size` option.

For e.g.:

```
    <div class="span12" style="background:url('img/middle.jpg') no-repeat; height:245px;background-size:auto 245px;">
        Hello world.
    </div>
```

In this example, it will always maintain the 245px. If you want it to maintain the screen width, then it's `background-size:100% auto;` (or `background-size:contain;` which is likely the same).

**Usage:**

`background-size: <bg-size-h> [ , <bg-size-v> ]`

where `<bg-size>` can be `<length>`,`<percentage>`, `auto` or simply one worded `cover` or `contain`

To maintain aspect-ratio, use `auto` as one of the options.

For more info, [CSS3 Background-Size](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/)